# How to convert shapefile to jvectormap using converter plugin?

Tags: python, shapefile, jvectormap

i followed all the steps specified in one of the similar post But it is not working for me, Please help:

1) I have followed all the steps provided by you and installed all the dependencies and softwares, I have downloaded file "ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces.zip" from http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-1-states-provinces/

2) I have created makemap.bat file with following command : python ^ converter.py ^ 10m-admin-1-states-provinces-shp/ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces.shp ^ 10m-admin-1-states-provinces-shp/jquery-jvectormap-data-russia-ru-en.js ^ --width 400 ^ --where "ISO_3166_2 = 'RU-' and code_hasc!=''" ^ --country_name_index 12 ^ --country_code_index 18 ^ --minimal_area 4000000 ^ --buffer_distance -0.5 ^ --simplify_tolerance 10000 ^ --longitude0 54.8270 ^ --name russia

3) Run OSGeo4W Shell , type command makemap.bat from converter directory:

4) Got an error : Traceback (most recent call last): File "converter.py", line 295, in converter.convert(args['output_file']) File "converter.py", line 143, in convert self.loadData() File "converter.py", line 88, in loadData self.loadDataSource( sourceConfig ) File "converter.py", line 129, in loadDataSource shapelyGeometry = shapely.wkb.loads( geometry.ExportToWkb() ) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wkb'

One more thing i have seen , i have opened SHP file in QGIS Browser to browse Attributes so that i can check for REGION and REGION CODE , but in case of above country REGION and REGION CODE is NULL.

Please help me on this. I need Russia and Singapore maps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add the line `import shapely.wkb` at the beginning of the `converter.py` script to solve issue 4). Hope this helps.